# Managing User's Role privilege in Angular JS client

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular fullstack generator

My web consist of 3 roles it is Employee, Employer, and Admin
I have a question about some several problem

**1st**

> app.constant.js

this is my order (user = employee)

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  angular.module("aApp.constants", [])

.constant("appConfig", {
    "userRoles": [
        "guest",
        "user",
        "employer",
        "admin"
    ]
});
})(angular);
```

but every time I've done with this quit my text editor it changed again to this order

```
(function(angular, undefined) {
  angular.module("aApp.constants", [])

.constant("appConfig", {
    "userRoles": [
        "guest",
        "user",
        "admin",
        "employer"
    ]
});
})(angular);
```

**2nd**

> Ng-show and privileges

And what is actually bothering me is this order affecting the view privilege between theses roles.

For instance, this is my navbar

```
<ul>
  <li ng-show="nav.isUser()" >Only for Employee </li> // User Li
  <li ng-show="nav.isEmployer()" >Only for Employer </li> // Employer Li
  <li ng-show="nav.isAdmin()">Only for Admin </li> //Admin Li
</ul>
```

The function is checking wether the role is user, employer, or admin.
But when I logged as User it only shows the User Li which is right. But when I logged in as  Employer it shows Employer Li and User Li also, which is not what I'd intend to have. And also with Admin it shows all of them. Foremost it all affected by the order in app.constant.js. Whenever I swap those roles order, the privileges to view changed according to that order.
What I want to achieve is that they only allowed to view their own view.

Any kind of help would really be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering if you missed here double quotes for employer(at the end) or this is actually your code pasted here - because this could cause a problem

Comment: no, it's a typo in this question, I'll fix that. It's really weird that this file change automatically to the original order where admin is below the user.

Comment: Add your code for 'nav.isUser()' etc

Comment: Weird - try to delete that file and paste the code in another one - I've got kind of weird same behaviour with css files - after editing it a lot of times

Comment: We do not know how you are checking your privileges, and the fact that your **text editor** changes this order for you is ... Unnatural. Which text editor are you using ?

Comment: I am using Sublime text, I don't know what is going on, have you ever use angular-fullstack-generator ? I'm guessing that there is some code or some gulp task that affecting this anywhere, but I still can't find it anywhere, the privilege is very crucial in this web.

Comment: it is obviously downright peculiar indeed, that the file change itself. but I want to know, what is affecting this privileges pertaining to the order of userRoles ?